# Java 8 Reducing Collector Identity Value too Limited?

Tags: java-8

In the case of parallel streams, you cannot pass in a list of objects as the identity and then hope to modify it since you will get a concurrent access error. This is understandable because there is only one of these such list of objects being operated on, the identity. It seems like something is missing. For instance, the other methods do allow you to map to list and also combine list. It is the first argument that is limiting. From my perspective, there should be another argument type for identity which would be a Supplier. This would not violate concurrent access and be much more flexible. At this point, I have a dummy identity and I have to do a check for the dummy identity to create that special list that Supplier would have created had it been an argument and would have been much cleaner.

My code is working. I think it is inelegant because of the above. Has anyone else arrived at this problem and come up with a better solution than a dummy identity?

Comment: Can you give an example code to better understand what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I would say you are probably using `reduce` incorrectly.

`reduce` should be used to return a single element (like `min()` or `max()` etc). if you are trying to have your reduce method return a collection, you are probably better off 
writing your code as a `Collector` which does take a `Supplier`

Javadoc for [`Stream.collect(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

Comment: This may be the right track since even using collect(reducing()) has the same problem with the non-supplier identity and I just need to take the more general and flexible approach as you mention.

Comment: I appreciate both answers but only have enough reps to mark one correct. I view this one as correct, albeit my question was not terribly clear. The reason being is that reducing in a collect has the same problem and a supplier is needed to accumulate values into a complex object (not just a list) and then have results of threads combined accordingly.

Comment: Update. I implemented the Collector interface with the much needed supplier. It is very natural approach to the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `collect()`, not `reduce()`.  The `reduce` methods operate on values; the identity is a value, not an empty container.  The `collect` methods allow you to do accumulations with mutable containers.  For example, if you want to collect the string representation of integers into a list:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
         .mapToObj(i -> Integer.toString(i))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A `Collector` is a tuple of functions that encapsulates the creation of an empty container (think ArrayList::new), the incorporation of a new element into a container (think ArrayList::add), and the merging of two containers (think ArrayList::addAll).  In fact, the above is largely equivalent to:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
         .mapToObj(i -> Integer.toString(i))
         .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
```

Comment: In this regard, I've switched to collect and then groupingBy followed by reducing but I'm having trouble with types at this point. I believe I'm on the right track since in this case the reducing will return one value per group rather than a list. It is either this approach or the one mentioned below.